# Is there a way I can disable HTTPS in Google via the URL?

Tags: ssl, https, google-document-viewer

For example, on basically every Google page I can include `hl=en`, which would set the language to English.

Is there a similar way I can stop Google from redirecting to using HTTPS? I am trying to do this with the Google Document Viewer.

When I say similar, I mean via the URL, like maybe `ssl=false`, or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a similar way I can stop Google from redirecting to using HTTPS?

No, Google are enforcing SSL.

Comment: by the way, is there a way I can debug why a Google Chrome tab crashes in Windows? I think asking a new question for this is unnecessary, so I'm just asking.